# Is it (patho)physiological, (patho-)physiological or (patho)-physiological?

Tags: grammar, hyphens, parenthesis

I'm not sure what the correct usage of hyphens is if they are used to provide a word alternative.

Example: These are released from cells under certain (patho)physiological conditions.

Bonus question: How is this grammatical construct called?

Comment: I think this changes the meaning actually. My question is also more generally regarding the positioning of hyphens within or outside of parentheses in these types of cases.

Comment: I made a mistake: the word in English is: physiopathology and physiopathological. There are no hyphens. The other is: pathophysiology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check any dictionaries?

[Merriam-Webster *pathophysiology*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathophysiological)

> the physiology of abnormal states; specifically : the functional changes that accompany a particular syndrome or disease

Since *pathophysiological* is derived from that, it has no added hyphens.

It's not a grammatical construct, just normal morphology of words.

As to showing an optional prefix for a word, I don't know of a convention for that. If you are writing something technical, you might be better off using more words rather than trying to get by with an abbreviation, at least on the first introduction of the term.

Comment: But I want to put the parenthesis for "patho" here since it is "optional". It has a meaning like "physiological or especially pathophysiological". Disregard the specific word if you want. How are hyphens used to make (optional) additions to a word. Or is this a construct that does not exist in english language?

Comment: @aKzenT That is usually not used in English. Physiological and especially pathophysiological conditions.

Comment: @aKzenT I don't know of a convention for showing an optional prefix for a word. If you are actually writing something technical, you might be better off using more words rather than trying to get by with an abbreviation.

Comment: This is a common construct in german and I thought it exists in english as well and was just wondering where to put the hyphen. But if this construct is unusual in English I will go with "physiological or pathophysiological" in this case. If you change your answer accordingly, I can accept it.